# Lost credit card replaced with new card and new numbers. Credit score affected?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I recently left my credit card at a bar so I reported it as lost to my bank, and my bank said I will get a replacement within a few days. For what it's worth, I picked my card up from the bar a few days later and made sure to cut it up.

The new credit card has arrived and has new numbers. Will this negatively affect my credit score?

VISA, Chase Bank, USA.

Comment: There should be no impact.

Comment: It will only potentially affect your credit in the case it is used for fraudulent activities in which your case you end up finding the card anyways.

Comment: @quid Do you have any resources which would provide me with a explanation of why?

Comment: @NuWin - even if there are fraudulent activites on a lost/stolen CC, this should still not affect your credit. If you dispute the charges you will not be responsible for paying them, and if you choose to pay them anyway (depending on who "steals" your card), then of course it also doesn't affect your credit.

Comment: @TTT not every fraudulent charge is disputed successfully.

Comment: @NuWin - so then you pay it just like any other charge and your credit isn't affected.

Comment: @TTT thanks for the tip. Next time someone charges thousands of dollars on my card I'll just pay it off just so it won't affect my credit.

Comment: You missed my point. This question is about changing your credit card number and whether doing that affects your credit. The answer is no, even if there were fraudulent charges. If you ever choose to not pay your credit card bill (for whatever reason), of course that will affect your credit, but that is true even if you don't get a new CC number.

Answer (score 8):

This will have no effect on your credit score.

Even though your credit card account number is changing, it is still the same account, so your history of payments and age of accounts will remain unchanged.

Comment: Is this true for all CC companies? Do you have any resources to back up your answer?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Credit card numbers change all the time. My credit card number changed three times last year, due to various incidences of fraud. It only shows up as one account on my credit report.

Comment: In addition to fraud/loss replacements, I have had one card replaced when the issuer merged and one when the issuer withdrew from a region and sold their portfolio to another bank; in all cases the credit report items continued seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The true answer is ***it depends*** because  it is up to the credit card issuer to follow the right path when issuing a replacement credit card.

---

http://www.bankrate.com/finance/credit-cards/will-replacement-card-hurt-my-score.aspx

> Typically, issuers will transfer the account history to the new trade line, says Barry Paperno, the consumer operations manager at FICO, the creator of the FICO scoring formula. The new account should have the old open date, so you should retain your payment history, he says. The credit limit and balance should also stay the same.

---

http://blog.credit.com/2014/02/lost-or-stolen-credit-card-hurt-your-credit-scores-76724/

> **How Issuers Report Replacement Cards**
>
> We asked the major card issuers how they report replacement cards to credit reporting agencies:
>
> **American Express:** The new card has the same open date and “Member Since” year as the previous card. The balance on the old account number is transferred to the new account number. All payment history transfers over.
>
> **Bank of America:** All transactions and account history are transferred to the new account number when there is a card replacement or renewal.
>
> **Capital One:** The new account number with all the original account data (original open date, etc.) is reported along with a notification to the bureaus that the new account number is replacing the old.  The two tradelines can then be ‘merged’ into one, so that all the applicable payment history, balance, etc. is now under the new account number.
>
> **Chase:** The original tradeline does not change. The history on the account remains, just the account number field is updated with the new account number. There is no “new” tradeline in this scenario.

Comment: I don't follow your logic that "it depends". All of your examples support Ben's answer that your credit score will not be affected. Can you provide an example of a company where it would affect your credit?